How to implement live video streaming with ffmpeg without using WebRTC?
Following up on my previous question, I'd like to inquire about alternative methods for live video streaming using ffmpeg (WebRTC is not an option due to certain constraints I prefer not to discuss here).
Context:
I have a Go application where a goroutine launches ffmpeg to process a video stream, which is then delivered to the main goroutine via a chan []byte. I tried using WebSocket, but encountered issues as described in the previous question. HLS also didn't work well due to significant latency and artifacts like green squares on the video.
Based on a comment in the previous question, I attempted to stream the video via a simple GET request. Here's the Go handler I implemented:
func stream(helperApp agent.Helper) func(rw http.ResponseWriter, rr *http.Request) {
   a := atomic.Bool{}
   return func(rw http.ResponseWriter, rr *http.Request) {
      if !a.CAS(false, true) {
         http.Error(rw, "already running", http.StatusInternalServerError)
         return
      }

      rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "video/mp2t")

      out := make(chan []byte)

      // create StreamParam
      go ScreenCaptureForLiveStream(StreamParam, out) // ffmpeg process starts inside

      r, w := io.Pipe()
      go func() {
         for data := range out {
            w.Write(data)
            fmt.Println(len(data))
         }
      }()
      io.Copy(rw, r)
   }
}


On the client side (HTML):
<video id="video" muted="muted" src="http://localhost:8080/stream" controls></video>

In the browser console, I can see data being received, but the video doesn't play.
FFmpeg is executed with these parameters:
-loglevel error -f avfoundation -framerate 5 -capture_cursor 1 -capture_mouse_clicks 1 -i 1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf pad='ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2' -threads 0 -preset veryfast -bf 2 -f mpegts pipe:1


For validation, I ran:
ffmpeg -i http://localhost:8080/stream -c copy out.mp4


The video was successfully saved and plays.
Question:
What alternative methods exist to implement live video streaming with ffmpeg, aside from WebRTC? Why does the current approach of streaming video via HTTP GET request not function correctly in the browser, and how can this be resolved?

Read about rtmp , it might help.

I notice your video tag does not have a type.  I wonder if the browser is failing to interpret the type?   I do see you have a content-type.  But I wouldn't assume just because ffmpeg figured it out that it's up to browser spec

@erik258
added a type, it didn't help. I tried "video/mp2t" and "video/mp4"

Not that this is a problem, but the io.Pipe and anonymous goroutine are unnecessary.  Replace that code with for data := range out { rw.Write(data); fmt.Println(len(data)) }.  You can eliminate the goroutine for ScreenCaptureForLiveStream and channel out by setting the ffmpeg stdout to the response writer.

(1) The body of the handler can run no more than one time.  Add defer a.Store(false) after the first if statement in the function. (2) Ensure that the request method is GET before starting the stream. (3)  Use CommandContext in ScreenCaptureForLiveStream where the context is rr.Context().

https://superuser.com/questions/1851055/how-to-set-different-output-qualities-for-mpeg-dash/1851117#1851117

If you want todo it correctly in 2024 either use fmp4 with mse or webrtc. Since you dont want usw webrtc you should use mse.

@SarathSadasivanPillai RTMP is not relevant here.  Browsers don't speak RTMP.

@JayCravens No, DASH is irrelevant here.  Streaming can be done directly with a GET request.

@Christoph That's nonsense, MSE is not required here.  There's no reason for that overhead, complexity, lack of client/container/codec options.  Streaming directly to the video element works just fine.

@Artem I don't know Go, but your code seems fine.  See my answer below for what at least one issue is.  If you get the content solved and all that but it still doesn't work, please post a public URL so I can test it from here and see what the next issue is.

@brad just sad how its done in professional setups ;) there is always the easy solution, and the correct one.

@Christoph The correct solution is the one that considered the specific project's constraints and requirements.  By all means, waste CPU, hurt your device compatibility, increase your latency, and add additional encoding constraints if you don't actually care.  Or, let the browser do the work for you, because it has to do that anyway when you shove data to it over MSE.  Might as well let it optimally handle the stream too.

@brad Sounds like you are a friend of MSE. ;) for us its the best solution because of buffer managment and error handling and ABR. We had also better latency, no cpu waste or other compatibily issues, but you are right always depense on Project requierements. In cctv systems we had already control over codecs etc. and so its easier in context of compatibily.

@Brad Irrelevant?  That's the purpose of DASH is adaptive bitrate over HTTP.  With a GET request.  It's just typically not a live stream, it's for quality selections, but that's not exclusive.

Have you tried using  application/x-mpegURL for the MIME type?

Connection lost/reconnect also not work with just using an url in Video Element. Also authentication could be hard

Friends, ABR works fine with a normal HTTP response.  MP4/ISOBMFF and WebM/Matroska all support changes in bit rate, frame size, frame rate, mid-stream.  You can even do quality and temporal scaling, if that is useful to you.  Now, if you want to factor in client resolution changes, page visibility changes, etc., you need out-of-band channel for that but it can be right over that same HTTP connection and is still more efficient than segmented methods such as HLS and DASH.

You're not going to be able to send MPEG-TS to the video element.  I recommend you use either WebM or MP4.
For WebM, in your FFmpeg command use -f webm, and then for your Content-Type use video/webm.
For MP4, you must also configure fragmentation, so use -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov, and then for Content-Type, use video/mp4.
You can reduce buffer time if you also include codecs in your Content-Type.
Also, since your stream is "live", I highly recommend setting preload="none" in your video tag.  Otherwise, the browser may want to pointlessly stream even though the user isn't playing the video.
If you want more control over your latency, keep an eye on the buffered property and drift playbackRate slightly more than 1.0 to catch up to realtime.  Don't go too far though or you'll have buffer underruns.  And of course, if something radical happens and you find yourself like, 20 seconds behind, you can always set currentTime to the latest time.
Using these methods, I'm able to get under 300 milliseconds glass-to-glass with no special optimization.  You can go lower than that if you carefully control your codec parameters... just remember, everything is a tradeoff.

You can send MPEG-TS to a <video> element with HLS.  That's what is on a .m3u8 playlist is .ts segments.

thank you, I did it according to your recommendations, the first frame was reflected in the player, but then the video does not play, although I see in the console that the data is coming

I found out the problem is ffmpeg video capture on mac OS, it works on windows. I haven't figured out what's wrong with macOS yet

@Artem Woot!  Glad you've been able to make progress.
